# Runtime initialization of character array in C using for loop

Tags: c

While initializing the character array at runtime using for loop statement inside are executed twice like printf function meanwhile character array of 6 size taking only 3 inputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

  int i = 0;
  char name[6];

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    printf("Enter the character in  name array");
    scanf("%c", &name[i]);
  }

  printf("%s", name);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: just throw away the loop and use `scanf("%6s", name)` and increase name size to 7 since you need to store the terminating 0 also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: @Eraklon  thanks a lot  but why i am not able to   initialize char  array using for loop

Comment: @crazyArtist look at the answer

Answer (score 5):

when you define an array of characters ,in the last element of array you should place `\0` to terminate string. so you can scan `5` characters as you do ,but you should add `\0` at the end of your string.

also you should add space to your `scanf` like this `scanf(" %c", &name[i]);` ,otherwise you will take `\n` as a character of your string after each time you use enter.(that is reason of problem you explained)

look

```
int main() {

    int i = 0;
    char name[6];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter the character in  name array");
        scanf(" %c", &name[i]);
    }
    name[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s", name);

    return 0;
}
```

also note that ,I have removed `int i` from here `for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)` , otherwise this `i` would be only visible in for loop block and out side of it, because of `int i = 0;`  `\0` would be placed in `name[0]` ,and string would be lost.

or use `scanf("%6s", name)` as @Eraklon said in comments.

Comment: @crazyArtist. feel free. No need for thanks. accept the answer if it was helpful.